# Trouble building full stack app with Express

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I've been trying to build a create-react-app + Express full stack app with typescript. However I can't figure out how to compile the server files to a build folder. I have seperate tsconfig files for the server and for create-react-app.

I want the files to go into `build/server`. The server ts files are located in `./server`, and React in `./src`.

tsconfig.json (supplied by create-react-app):

```
{ "compilerOptions":

{ "target": "es5",

"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],

"allowJs": true,

"skipLibCheck": true,

"esModuleInterop": true,

"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

"strict": true,

"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

"module": "esnext",

"moduleResolution": "node",

"resolveJsonModule": true,

"isolatedModules": true,

"noEmit": true,

"jsx": "preserve" },

"include": ["src"]}
```

tsconfig.server.json:

```
{ "extends": "./tsconfig.json",

"compilerOptions":

{ "module": "commonjs",

"outDir": "build/server" },

"include": ["server"]}
```

I am trying to build with

```
tsc -p tsconfig.server.json
```

I get no errors, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

Create-react-app supplies "noEmit": true as a config option, which means the change won't be committed to the build folder. Specifying "noEmit": false in the server tsconfig.json solved the issue.